# Bar legend coloring doesn't correspond to array plot coloring in the expected way

Tags: plotting, legending

Execute this code:

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}],
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}],
 PlotRange -> {-5, 1},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

In my PC (Xubuntu 15.04, *Mathematica* 10.3) this returns:

[image]

You can see that the `BarLegend` is wrong, it should be:

[image]

which is what I get if I had executed `BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}]` directly.

Is this a bug? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can confirm this happens in 10.3 Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: @Edmund not a bug, user error.

Comment: Why the close vote? It may not be a bug, but the proper way to do this is not in the documentation. So this is a valid question.

Comment: @becko not mine. I think it is a good question. I just upvoted it.

Comment: I would disagree that it is not an error.  The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) clearly states that a legend constructor can be used for `PlotLegends` and even explictly includes `BarLegend` in in the list. The OP has used a valid option and a valid expression for the option and has not gotten the expected result.

Comment: @Edmund I disagree. The user specified a `ColorFunction` in _both_ the plot itself and the legend. This was the error as `PlotLegends -> Automatic` (and variants) will pick up the _correct_  `ColorFunction` which the documentation states.

Comment: @rcollyer `BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}]` completely specifies the legend.  The error is that a completely specified legend is being manipulated. There is no request for alteration with this specification. Just as `PlotLegends -> "Apples"` is not altered so to should `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}]` not be altered. `BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}]` is a complete expression with no `Automatic`, `Full`, or any other symbols that would cause it to be altered.

Comment: @Edmund But, the legend functions are special in `PlotLegends` processing, so things like `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` are added to ensure that the correct thing is done normally. I will send your comments to the developers, though, as I can see your point.

Comment: @rcollyer I have to agree with Edmund. Maybe it is not a bug, in the sense that this is how it is designed. But in that case, the design is questionable.

Comment: @Edmund after re-thinking this, I have to say it is only on the surface that it looks like the legend is completely specified. There are several options with `Automatic` (and other) values that take on what is set in the corresponding plot. For example, `LabelStyle`, `Joined`, `LegendMarkerSize`, etc. are all set by the enclosing plot. To completely specify a legend, then, all of those options will have to be set. This ensures consistent behavior. Otherwise, we would have people complain that we weren't being consistent, and a different group would be left unsatisfied. :)

Comment: @rcollyer So it seems that it is slightly a case of perspective to some degree.  That being said `Evaluate@` does not protect it.  I would expect that this would since it should resolve before `PlotLegends` gets it.  Interesting that `Pane@` does protect it.

Comment: @Edmund perspective and trade-offs based on who you satisfy. In other words, the usual stuff with complex systems. `Evaluate` won't protect it as they're inert, all the "magic" happens during the display phase; same with `Graphics`. So, `Evaluate@legendfunction` evaluates to `legendfunction`. It is curious that `Pane` does protect it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using it wrong. The default algorithm for `PlotLegends` will supply the correct `ColorFunction` to `BarLegend`, so use

```
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}], 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 1}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

If you need to modify the legend, you can do so without mishap by using `Automatic`, e.g.

```
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {-10, 10}}]
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 5 (*contours*)]
```

etc.

Comment: This should be documented. It is not obvious that this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @becko It is in the details section of [ref/BarLegend](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html). As always, there could be more examples of it ...

Answer (score 3):

Can confirm this happens in 10.3 Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

You can get around it with `Legended`.

```
Legended[
 ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}], 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}], 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 1}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
 BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: To the downvoter, if this were a _bug_ this would be a good way of working around the problem, and was my solution.

Comment: I would disagree that it is not an error.  The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) clearly states that a legend constructor can be used for `PlotLegends` and even explictly includes `BarLegend` in in the list.

Comment: @Edmund answered above.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind there are four ways of making the array plot with the BrownCyanTones gradient and a bar legend that seem reasonable.

#### Data range -1 to 1, plot range -1 to 1, lengend range -1 to 1

```
SeedRandom[1];
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}],
  ColorFunction -> "BrownCyanTones",
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image: plot1]

#### Data range -5 to 1, plot range -5 to 1, lengend range -5 to 1

```
SeedRandom[1];
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{-5, 1}, {10, 10}],
  ColorFunction -> "BrownCyanTones",
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}]]
```

[image: plot2]

#### Data range -1 to 1, plot range -1 to 1, legend colors taken from the upper part of BrownCyanTones

```
SeedRandom[1];
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}], 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {-1, 1}}],
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {-1, 1}}], {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image: plot3]

#### Data range -1 to 1, plot range -5 to 1, lengend range -5 to 1

```
SeedRandom[1];
ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}], 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones", {-1, 1}}],
  PlotRange -> {-5, 1},
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"BrownCyanTones", {-5, 1}}]]
```

[image: plot4]

I can't figure out from your question which of these is what you are after, but one of them should work. They all have the property that the bar legend colors match the plot colors.