# How to synchronise bar legends zeros for a set of DensityPlots?

Tags: plotting, color

I make a set of 6 `DensityPlot`s with `PlotLegends` and different sets of `params`:

```
DensityPlot[(a^3/h^2)^-1 fun[x, y, {a, h, V}, g] /. params
 , {x, xmin, xmax} /. params // Evaluate
 , {y, ymin, ymax} /. params // Evaluate
 , Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> framelbl /. params // Evaluate
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , PlotRange -> All
 , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
 , PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic
   (*,LegendFunction\[Rule]Framed*)
   , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Black}
   , LegendLabel -> "\[Zeta]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
StyleBox[\"h\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"], \(2\)]\)/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[
StyleBox[\"a\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"], \(3\)]\)"
   , LegendMarkerSize -> 180]
 , MaxRecursion -> maxrecursions /. params // Evaluate
 , PlotPoints -> plotpoints /. params // Evaluate
 , BaseStyle -> {16}
 , ImageSize -> Medium
 , Epilog -> {White, Disk[{0.9, 0.9} // Scaled, 0.05 // Scaled]
   , Black, Text[lbl, {0.9, 0.9} // Scaled] /. params // Evaluate
   }
 ]
```

Unfortunately, coloring of the plots turn out to be quite different because maximal and minimal values of function `fun` varies from plot to plot. Even zero level of `fun` has different color in different plots as shown below:
[image]

I guess that zero level could get same color in all pictures if `ColorFunction` will be scaled assuming that maximal an minimal values of `fun` are the same by absolute value and differs by their sign only. How to do that?

**Update**: Although there are several similar posts at this forum, which allows to solve my problem by preliminary computation of minimal and maximal values of plotted function I would be totally satisfied if such a computation could be automated. I mean that DensityPlot internally for sure computes these values as it by defaults scales color data to the range {0,1}. Is it possible to retrieve these internal values and feed them to `ColorFunction[...,{-1,1}*Max@Abs[{InternalMin, InternalMax}]]`, where `InternalMin` and `InternalMax` are these internally computed values?

Comment: You have to find the minimum and maximum value of the set of six plots. Using this information, and an appropriate `ColorFunction` which could use `Rescale` together with a setting of `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` would do what you want.

Comment: Would you like every image to be using exactly the same color scale? Or just that every image has the same color at 0? Also you should consider whether you really want a Rainbow color map. Your data should really use a divergent isoluminal colormap, have a google about why rainbow is so bad!

Comment: You may find information relevant to your problem in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105007/3066)

Comment: @Quantum_Oli: Preferebly, I want to have different scales for different plots as I am afraid that with common scale figure a will look almost monochrome.

Comment: related q/a: [Set the same color scale across multiple ListContourPlots?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64330/125)