# Is it possible to mark a legend in density plot manually

Tags: plotting

I was using the code as `DensityPlot[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 1, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ImageSize -> Small]`
which gives the output as 
[image]

And another code is `DensityPlot[Sin[x - y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 1, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ImageSize -> Small]`
which gives the output as
[image]

We can see that the BarLagends for both images are not at the equal footing here, but I need these legends on equal footing so that I would be able to compare them. Is it possible to do so? Or can we mark the ticks on legends manually? Please help me!

Actually, first I made a 3D-plot of these two functions, Sin[x+y] and Sin[x-y], in a single frame. So it was easy to compare them but due to some reasons I can't use a 3D plot in my work. Then I thought it would be another good option to compare them.

Comment: Define "footing."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork By the word "footing", I mean to say that first figure is having range from {-1.0,1.0} and the other one is with {-1.0,0.8}, i.e. not matching the previous one.

Comment: I should have used scaling or range of plots in the place of footing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Although [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105007/3066) concerns `ArrayPlot` rather than `DensityPlot`, you may find its exposition of plot and legend scaling helpful.